# How to use Robotium with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, robotium

[Robotium](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium) is an Android test automation framework that has full support for native and hybrid applications.

Now that Android Studio is the *de facto* IDE for Android development, I'm interested to try this with Android Studio. However, I couldn't find a way to set it up.

How to setup and use Robotium to test with Android Studio?

Comment: Robotium wiki also has [a step-by-step guide for Android Studio](http://anirudh24seven.github.io/devlog/2015/02/13/robotium-android-studio.html) (posted long after the only answer here)

Answer (score 40):

**Guide:**

1. Add the following line to the **dependencies** section of the inner build.gradle file (this file is located at the same level as **src** folder), change version name if required:

   ```
   androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'
   ```

   If for some reason you don't want to let gradle download dependencies for you then
   you can add them manually: Place robotium.jar into the **libs** folder. Right click it and select **Add as library...**
2. In the **src** folder create another folder **androidTest**
3. Inside it create **java** folder
4. (Optional step, see below) Inside it create a package for the test source with the same name as app’s package name (or add ".tests" to its end.)
5. Place cursor (in the Editor window) at the class name inside one of the files that you want to test (e.g. MainActivity) and press Alt+Enter.
6. Select **Create Test**. Select the proper superclass for Robotium:

   ```
   android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
   ```
7. Android studio will create a test file and a package (if it wasn’t created in step 6)
8. How to run the test:

   - UI: as usual using Android Studio **Run** menu
   - console: in the terminal enter the following command:

     ```
     ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
     ```

     The HTML-reports will be generated at "YourApp/YourApp/build/outputs/reports/androidTests/
     connected/index.html"

Comment: The video link goes to this stackoverflow page

Comment: @aat thank you for your remark. There was another answer in this thread that had a link to some live code event that talked about this topic. That answer was removed and unfortunately the video is not available anymore. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Why do you need to add robotium.jar manually to your libs (step 1)? If you add dependency as in step 3 gradle should automatically resolve dependency from maven central.

Comment: @lenrok258 thank you for your remark! You are absolutely right. It is better to let gradle handle dependencies instead of doing it manually. Updated my answer.