# Robotium integration testing in Android Studio for custom soft keyboard

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-softkeyboard, robotium, android-input-method

I've seen a few articles on how to set up Robotium with Android Studio, such as this link http://anirudh24seven.github.io/devlog/2015/02/13/robotium-android-studio.html or this link [How to use Robotium with Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275602/robotium-with-android-studio). However, I have yet to get it working to test my custom soft keyboard. What I've got so far is to create a `test/java` folder under `/src/` in my module and modify build.gradle to include `compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'`. Note that I created `test/java` instead of `androidTest/java` as suggested in above links because otherwise the `java` folder wouldn't turn green. Now I don't know what to set for the launcher activity. I would ideally like to automate UI for the keyboard somehow and test the values/resources that are being displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.4.1 has been released

Comment: does that have specific support for testing input method service that wasn't available before?